# Can factoring $90$ help factor $91$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

There are few posts asking if  factoring $N-1$ can help factor $N$. In those posts the focus was on the factors of $N-1$ and $N$ which can never be the same. The conclusion therefore was that factoring $N-1$ cannot help factor $N$.
In this post the focus is shifted to the numbers $N$ and $N-1$ neighbors. It turned out that when the two numbers have a neighbor of a special form with the same numerical value it becomes possible to use factoring $N-1$ to factor $N$.

We consider numbers of the form $N=pq$ with $p,q$ primes of the form $p=6k_{1}+1$ and $q=6k_{2}+1$. Then $N$ can be written as $N=36k_{1}k_{2} + 6(k_{1} + k_{2}) + 1$.
It turned out that many numbers share the same value of $36k_{1}k_{2}$ though they have of course different factors. We will show below how we go from factoring $N-1=90$ to factoring $N=91$.

$91=7*13=(6*1+1)(6*2+1)= 6*6*2 + 6*(1+2) +1 = 6*12 +3*6 +1= 72 + 19$
$90=9*10= (8 + 1)(9 + 1)= 8*9 + 18 = 72 + 18 = 6*12 + 18$
Since $91$ and $90$ have the same value of $36k_{1}k_{2}=72$, it is therefore possible to use the same value of $72$ to get that of $91$ by writing $91= (6+1)*(12+1)$ simply because $8*9=6*12=72$ since $72$ can be written as $72=(p-1)(q-1)=6*12$

Basically it was possible to use factoring of $N-1$ to factor $N$ by using the common value of $72$ which is $72=(p-1)(q-1)$ for $91=pq$ and $72=(f-1)(h-1)$ for $90=fg$. But there are more numbers having the same value of $72$ because $72$ can be written as:
$72=1*72=2*36=3*24=4*18=6*12=8*9$ giving the corresponding numbers $M=146,111,100,95,91,90$. However $90$ was the most useful since we were looking for numbers of the form $N-1$ to see if they can help factor $N$. But $95=91+4$ would have done the job too but we couldn't know in advance which number would share the value of $36k_{1}k_{2}$ of $N=91$.

For example $133=7*19$ share the same value of $36k_{1}k_{2}=108=6*18=9*12$ as $N-3=130=10*13$.

Large numbers of the form $N=pq$ with $p,q$ primes would have a large value of $36k_{1}k_{2}$ whose decomposition will produce many more numbers that could in theory be possible candidates to play the role of $(N-1),(N-2),(N-3)...$. What we don't want is replacing the difficulty of factoring $N$ with the difficulty of finding a number $(N-x)$ or $(N+x)$ that can be easily factored. These numbers are not of the form $L=pq$ like the example of $90=2*3^2*5$ or $130=2*5*13$ so the hope of them being easier to factor is there.

**The main question is**: How easy is-it to find and factor one of those candidates when they are large, that is when we are dealing with numbers with hundreds of digits? We may still spend time searching for a good candidate by varying $x$ in $(N-x)$ or $(N+x)$.

Comment: This has been answered. The answer is "no". For so small numbers , it is helpful because we can rule out the factors of $N$ , but for large $N$, this helps virtually nothing , in particular if we try to factor $N-1$ or $N+1$

Comment: I will provide this example to show that there is no difference between the case $N$ and $N-1$ or $N-9$. Suppose we wanted to factor $N=7*31=217$. We tried to find an $N-1$ but could not. So we tried $N-2$, $N-3$, $N-4$, $N-5$, $N-6$, $N-7=210=10*21$. So $(10-1)*(21-1)=180=5*36=9*20=6*30$. Now $5*36$ will give $K=6*37=222$. $6*30$ will give $L=7*31=217$, the number we started with. So in this case $N-7=210$ saved the day. However the following list gives all numbers with $(p-1)*(q-1)=180$ for primes and $(f-1)*(g-1)$ for mixtures of factors prime and composites. (Cont )

Comment: Cont-  List: $362$, $273$, $244$, $230$, $222$, $217$, $210$, $209$ and $208$.

Comment: @Peter, I provided this example above to show that numbers $N$ can be factored with the help of $(N-x)$ or $(N+x)$ with x different from $-1$ or $1$. I don't think large numbers behave differently than small ones because for large number $36k_{1}k_{2}$ will also be large and will provide a lot more numbers that can be used, some of which may be easily factored because their factors will be close to each other in which case using Fermat method will be enough to factor them.

Comment: Then factor $24!-1$ using the factorization of $24!$ if you think this method works for larger numbers as well.

Comment: In the comment above, it was shown that in $(N-x)$, x doesn't have to be $1$ or $-1$. It means that $x$ can be any integer. The proof (that you may offer) that $24!-1$ cannot help factor $24!$ does not mean $24!-x$ cannot help factor $24!$. I provided more than one example of $x=1,3,7$ to show precisely that $x$ is not limited to being $1,-1$ but you apparently refused to see that.